# Scanning range and paste copied information if a certain cell is empty

Tags: google-apps-script

i'm still a beginner in this, so I might ask a lot of stupid questions.
My problem is the following:
I wrote this script:

```
function ThisTry() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var Ssheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Recap");
 var nSheet = sheet.getSheetByName("Aktuell");
 var rang1 = sheet.getRange("Aktuell!A1:Q28");
 var colum = 1;
 var columEnd = 20;
 var ro = 85;
 var roEnd = 112;
 var clean = nSheet.getRange(29, 20);
 var ad = clean.getValue();
 if (ad == "", ro+=28, false); 
 if (ad == "", roEnd+=28, false);  
 var past = rang1.copyValuesToRange(Ssheet, colum, columEnd, ro, roEnd);
  }
```

What I am doing is I copy some information from one sheet and paste it in another. But i want to create a code that watches if a certain cell is empty or not and if it is not I want to change the values of the variables that I use to define the range in copyValuesToRange in the code above.
This code currently works but it doesn't save the new values of the variables, so it does what it should the first time but after that it doesn't change the range
I know that my if statements are wrong but I have no idea how to fix them so that the code works.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If someone is editing the contents of clean' you can check the value after an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder) trigger event to see if the current value is different from the past value.  You can maintain state between function calls by storing information in [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service).  I also like just storing stuff in files as ascii text because you can store so much stuff all in one place and if need be you can edit it with something like Drive Notepad.  If your interested in that then spend some time learning about [Drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app).

If you wish to poll that value, then you could run code from a sidebar or dialog using Javascript timer functions and you can call any server side with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run). In addition, that's a way to build sort of a control panel to watch the process from.

I don't know exactly what your trying to accomplish but I hope that I've given you some useful things to consider.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information! I'll definitely check the links out. 
So to explain what I want to do: I have a table where every day new information is added by different people. So the table is divided by days of the week. At the end of the week I want to take all information (days of the week, dates, and all information that was added for every weekday) and copy it in another sheet. The purpose of the second sheet is to make it easier for everyone to use the original sheet without scrolling through 100 days until they find the current date and to avoid confusion. I hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that information. Have you considered using a form that's linked to you spreadsheeet for data entry.  The form will come up clean for each user  and the data they will be posted to the spreadsheet.